# PHP Password_verify always returns false no matter what?

Tags: php, authentication, registration

I am creating a login and registration system in php. I am using php's password_hash and password_verify functions in the same class.

Every time I try and check the password it returns false.

My sql password row is set to TEXT.

Here is my user class for creating and logging users in.

```
<?php 
/**
* 
*/
class User
{
    private $pdo;
    function __construct()
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function newUser($username, $email, $password)
    {
        global $pdo;
        //check if username is taken
        $checkUsername = $this->checkUsername($username);
        if (!$checkUsername) {
            $checkEmail = $this->checkEmail($email);
            if (!$checkEmail) {
                $hashPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                if ($hashPass) {
                    $upload = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)");
                    $upload->execute(array(":username"=>$username, ":password"=>$hashPass, ":email"=>$email));

                    if ($upload) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return false;
        //check if email in use
        //hash password
        //uplaod user
    }

    public function checkUsername($username)
    {
        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
        $sql->execute(array(":username"=>$username));

        $rows = $sql->fetchColumn();
        if ($rows) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function checkEmail($email)
    {
        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :email LIMIT 1");
        $sql->execute(array(":email"=>$email));

        $rows = $sql->fetchColumn();
        if ($rows) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function loggedin()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
            if ($_SESSION['username'] !== "Anonymous") {
                if ($_SESSION['loggedin']) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function login($username, $password)
    {
        global $pdo;
        if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {
            //check if username exists
            $checkUsername = $this->checkUsername($username);
            if ($checkUsername) {
                //get db pass
                $DBPass = $pdo->prepare("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1");
                $DBPass->execute(array(":username"=>$username));
                $pass = $DBPass->fetchColumn();
                //verify password
                if ($pass) {
                    $verify = password_verify($password, $pass);
                    if ($verify) {
                        return true;
                    }else{
                        return "5";
                    }
                }else{
                    return "4";
                }
            }else{
                return "3";
            }
        }else{
            return "2";
        }

        return "1";
    }
    }
```

The return; 1,2,3,4,5 are just for debugging to see where it goes wrong, It always returns 5. Even if I register and user, logout and then logout.

P.s, if anyone has any security tips with the code, please comment them!

Thanks!

Comment: what is the size of column for password in database?

Comment: Do you have multiple users with the same user name in the database?

Comment: @B.Desai It hasn't been set, It is just a text column.

Comment: @Erik No, That's what the checkUsername() function is for.

Comment: OT: When using `if(...){ return true; }else{ return false; }` you do not need an extra `return false; ` There are only these two options. This will make the code a lot easier to read. The same goes for the cascading `else` parts in `newUser` and `loggedin`

Comment: will you `echo $pass;` and check whether it s correct or not

Comment: I don't get the `checkUsername` part ... if the query for the *password* returns a value, the username obviously exists, otherwise it doesn't.